# Rails -nokogiri GEM: Detect MIME type of image in URL

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mime

I am using gem `nokogiri` to scrap `img` tag `src` values.
Sometimes `url` doesn't show the image file name with extension.

So I am trying to detect the image `MIME` type as follows:

```
MIME::Types.type_for("http://web.com/img/12457634").first.content_type # => "image/gif"
```

But it shows error:

```
undefined method `content_type' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Any solution?

Comment: yes it works very well.

Comment: Great :) Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get this error:

```
undefined method `content_type' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

because the `MIME::Types.type_for("http://web.com/img/12457634").first` object is `nil` sometimes.

To avoid this problem, do this:

```
MIME::Types.type_for("http://web.com/img/12457634").first.try(:content_type)
```

So, it does not crash your program if it's `nil`. If it's not `nil`, you get the correct `content_type`

Alternatively, to check the `Content-Type` header for image using `Net::HTTP`, you can write a method like this:

```
def valid_image_exists?(url)
    url = URI.parse(url)
    Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
      return http.head(url.request_uri)['Content-Type'].start_with? 'image'
    end
end
```